# Distribution of X/(X+Y)of gamma variables

Tags: gamma-distribution

Does anyone know how to calculate the distribution of $$X/(X+Y)$$
X  ~ G(p,a)

Y~G(p,b)

G is gamma distribution

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795168/beta-distribution-as-ratio-involving-gamma-distributions

Comment: The answer depends on the *joint* distribution, not just the margins. Presuming you mean for them to be independent, the question has been asked and answered multiple times already.